# Gradle C Plugin by Example

Tags: c, gradle, eclipse-cdt

On my local file system I have the following C project directory structure:

```
derpus/
    src/
        derpus/
            c/
                derpus.c
            headers/
    build.gradle
```

Where `derpus.c` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Derp!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would like to use the [Gradle Native (C) Plugin](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html) to manage the full spectrum of the `derpus` build. Specifically I would like Gradle to:

1. Generate a Gradle wrapper so that I can use `gradlew` for all my build invocations; and
2. Compile & build `derpus` into `derpus.exe` via `gradlew`; and
3. Generate Eclipse project info when I run `gradlew eclipse` so I can then import the project into Eclipse (I have already pre-installed the Eclipse CDT plugin)

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'c'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sources {
    c {
        source {
            srcDir "src/derpus/c"
            include "**/*.c"
        }
        exportedHeaders {
            srcDir "src/derpus/headers"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Obviously I should be able to run `gradle wrapper` to take care of the first item. But as for compiling and building, no where in the C plugin docs do I actually see a command or build invocation *that actually runs a compile and build*!

As for the third item, using the Eclipse plugin and invoking it via `gradlew eclipse`, I'm wondering if there's anything else I need to do so that the resultant project/settings configs are compatible with what the Eclipse CDT plugin expects in order to work with C programs. Although I intend to let Gradle handle all my builds, I still want to do all my development in Eclipse, and so all the things that CDT comes with (syntax highlighting, compiling, etc.) is important to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I figured all 3 out, and thought I would post this answer for any future readers.

Please note: This solution is really on viable for modern C programmers who:

- Want to do all *development* in Eclipse, taking advantage of modern IDE facilities like syntax highlighting, error, goto declaration, open call hierarchy, Eclipse's debugger, etc.; **but...**
- Want a modern, kick-a** build system like Gradle to do all the command-line/shell building

Furthermore, because I'm on Windows, I chose to use MinGW for my GCC provisioning, and so if you're either on *nix or Mac, or if you prefer Cygwin, you'll have to customize this solution even further.

Even furthermore, I have only verified this works with Eclipse Luna, using the latest Eclipse CDT plugin (8.6) and using Gradle 2.3.

## Solution

First I had to correct my usage of the C plugin, changing my `build.gradle` to look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'c'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

model {
    components {
        derpus(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                c(CSourceSet) {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/c"
                        include "**/*.c"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/headers"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

This allowed me to run `gradle wrapper` without any errors.

Next, I began to find it very peculiar that the Gradle Native Binaries documentation *never* mentions the build invocation for compiling/building native executables. I took a wild guess that it might be leveraging Gradle's "convention over configuration" approach, and I ran `gradlew build` - voila! Great success. Now under `derpus/build/binaries/derpusExecutable` I have `derpus.exe`! So far, so good.

The real headache sets in when you want to now import this Gradle-managed project into Eclipse, but still have Eclipse CDT provide all the normal features of a modern C IDE.

I started off by running `gradlew eclipse`, which added the following files under the `derpus/` project root:

- `.project`
- `.settings/language.settings`

I opened Eclipse and imported it as a project, however I got all sorts of errors, and when I hovered over `#include <stdio.h>` in my `derpus.c` file, and clicked `F3`, Eclipse did nothing. Clearly something was still not configured right. And so I got to hacking.

Turns out you just need to:

- Of course, first make sure the CDT plugin is installed and working correctly (doh!)
- Create a "dummy" C project in Eclipse, which will allow you to copy n' paste Eclipse CDT-generated settings/configs to your *actual* project
- Modify your actual `.project` file to include the same `<buildSpec />` and `<natures />` elements that were generated in the dummy project's `.project` file
- Copy the dummy project's `.cproject` file over to your actual project's root, and then open it in a text editor. You want to rename ALL instances of the dummy project's name with the name of your actual project; in my case there were 3 instances. In my case, my dummy project was literally named `dummy`, and my actual project is named `derpus`. So I had to change 3 instances of `dummy` to `derpus` in this file.
- Restart Eclipse

Your actual project will now behave exactly the same way as a C project created with the CDT plugin. Don't forget to delete you "dummy" project ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the c++ nature to the project with help of:

1. create a gradle project
2. select the project
3. use Eclipse->new->other
4. select c++ -> convert to a c++ project
5. clean up the project

Comment: Worked for me by first importing as Gradle project and afterwards adding the C/C++ nature as mentioned above (Eclipse Oxygen / Gradle 4.0). No fiddling around with configuration files!

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, gradle version 6.2.2, new C++ plugin can be used for the task. wrapper task is exist by default. Eclipse task available by adding eclipse plugin.

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp-application'
    id 'eclipse'
}

application {
    binaries.configureEach {
        def compileTask = compileTask.get()
        compileTask.source.from fileTree(dir: "src/derpus/c", include: "**/*.c")
        if (toolChain instanceof VisualCpp) {
            compileTask.compilerArgs = ["/TC"]
        } else if (toolChain instanceof GccCompatibleToolChain) {
            compileTask.compilerArgs = ["-x", "c", "-std=c11"]
        }

        def linkTask = linkTask.get()
        if (toolChain instanceof GccCompatibleToolChain) {
            linkTask.linkerArgs = ["-nodefaultlibs", "-lc"]
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/gradle/native-samples/tree/master/c/application

Comment: No need to set specific compiler and linker flags, probably. Works without them as of january 2022. Even for mixed C/C++ sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this (with Gradle 4.3), and I'd like to point out that you can simplify the `model` section to:

```
model {
    components {
        derpus(NativeExecutableSpec)
    }
}
```

because the source directory defaults to `"src/derpus/c"` anyway.